# Is it possible to add in python class object's values to list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making my own little game on python but I have little problem.
I'm trying to use class attribute with using only variables and i don't know if it's possible or how to do it right.

I'm kinda out of ideas and couldn't find answers from the net. This problem doesn't prevent my programming but it would be a lot easier if could make this work.

I'm making turn-based fighting game. I have two types of resistance: armor and shields. They both can block certain kind of magic. Every character has some kind of armor and shields. The function ajjaa ads their armors and shields to lists that tell what kind of magic they resistances. I could use armor_types function on both only changing the meaning of the obj variable.

Here is part of my code(It works just fine when I delete obj variable and use instead hardcoded armor/shield):

```py
class Fighter:
    def __init__(self, nimi, fdmg, tdmg, hp, armor, shield):
        self.nimi = nimi
        self.tdmg = tdmg
        self.fdmg = fdmg
        self.hp = hp
        self.armor = armor
        self.shield = shield

namelist = ["Lilah", "Morton", "King", "Sariel", "Leaf"]
tdmg = [50, 45, 40, 35, 30]
fdmg = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
hp = [100, 90, 80, 70, 60]
types = []
firetype = []
icetype = []
armor = ["t", "f", "f", "t", "f"]
shield = ["f", "t", "t", "t", "f",]

def add_lists():
    types.append(firetype)
    types.append(icetype)

def armor_types(myfighter,numberx,obj):
   print (myfighter.obj)
   if myfighter.obj == 't':
      if numberx == 0 or numberx == 8:
         firetype.append(myfighter.obj)
         if numberx == 0:
            myfighter.obj = 0.97
         if numberx == 8:
            myfighter.obj = 0.97
      if numberx == 1 or numberx == 9:
         icetype.append(myfighter.obj)
         if numberx == 1:
            myfighter.obj = 0.97
         if numberx == 9:
            myfighter.obj = 0.97
   print(myfighter.obj)


def main(numberx):
    add_lists()
    for x in namelist:
        myfighter = Fighter(x, tdmg[numberx], fdmg[numberx], hp[numberx], armor[numberx], shield[numberx])
        print(myfighter.armor)
        armor_types(myfighter,numberx,'armor')
        armor_types(myfighter,numberx,'shield')
        numberx += 1

main(0)
```

It just shows an error, but it should be added two to mylist.
I hope i explained problem right because I don't speak english as my native language. If there is ajjaa somwhere please tell me. aijjaa meant armor_types funcion.

Comment: Could you write a fuller [mcve] that demonstrates what you want to do?  It would also be helpful to see the error you're getting.

Comment: Why doesn't the first example work for you?  What does it do, and what did you want instead?

Comment: Show us the definition of functions `one` & `two`, along with the class. Also include this initialization: `mylist = []`

Comment: By the way, unless `ajjaa` is a common word in a language other than English and you're writing the rest of the code in that same language, that is a very bad method name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time to understand the problem because your really posted too much code. It could boil down to:

Impossible to access a parameterized attribute of object in following code:

```
class Fighter:
    def __init__(self, armor, shield):
        self.armor = armor
        self.shield = shield


def armor_types(myfighter, obj):
    return myfighter.obj

f = Fighter(2,3)
print(armor_types(f, 'armor'))
```

raising exception at `return myfighter.obj`:

```
AttributeError: 'Fighter' object has no attribute 'obj'
```

While it works fine with hardcoded attributes (`myfighter.armor`)

#### Explaination of the problem:

The language only allows `obj.attr` for hardcoded attributes. What should happen in above code if the object also contained an `obj` attribute?

#### Solution:

What you need are the builtin functions `getattr` and `setattr`. In above code, you could use:

```
def armor_types(myfighter, obj):
    return getattr(myfighter, obj)
```

and to change a parameterized attribute:

```
setattr(myfighter, obj, new_value)
```